# Cookies/Persistent Data Storage in an Opera TV Store App

Tags: cookies, opera, persistent-data

I am developing a smart tv app and due to the nature of the app it is necessary to store small amounts of data on the device.

It seems other platforms (like Samsung Smart TV) have the capability of storing data on the device.

I cannot find anything like that for the Opera TV Store (in their limited documentation) and it also seems that cookies will not work on a device. My app can correctly store and read cookies when ran from a browser on a PC, however on device nothing happens. Perhaps cookies are disabled?

If so, is there any other way to store data with an Opera TV Store app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether Opera TV support HTML5 well or not but this worth to try: [HTML5 WebStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to store limited amount of data in cookies. The limitations are due to platform limitations. The best way is to store data on servers. In order to detect returning users you can use check "uid" get parameter passed to apps when launched from the TV Store.